# Combining Kendo's batch editing and multiple row selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I am very new to Kendo and am having some difficulties.

I am having trouble creating a kendo grid where I can use the grid selection feature (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/selection 2nd example) to do batch inline editing (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing).

Essentially, I want to be able to select multiple CELLS (not rows - so the second example in the link above), and start typing to edit all of the selected cells.

The closest I've gotten so far is creating something where I can select multiple cells and press a button to generate a predetermined value, but this is not what I want.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
               var crudServiceBaseUrl = "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service",
                    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        transport: {
                            read:  {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                                dataType: "jsonp"
                            },
                            update: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                                dataType: "jsonp"
                            },
                            destroy: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                                dataType: "jsonp"
                            },
                            create: {
                                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                                dataType: "jsonp"
                            },
                            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        batch: true,
                        pageSize: 20,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "ProductID",
                                fields: {
                                    ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                    ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
                                    UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                                    Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                    UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                $("#cellSelection").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    selectable: "multiple cell",
                    pageable: {
                        buttonCount: 5
                    },
                    scrollable: false,
                    navigatable: true,
                    columns: [
                        "ProductName",
                        { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: 120 },
                        { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: 120 },
                        { field: "Discontinued", width: 120 },
                        { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 150 }],
                    editable: true
                });
            });
```

Thanks for any help